# Huge JavaScript Nested For Loops Causing Freeze

Tags: javascript

My program has 9 nested for-loops, in order to run through every permutation of a list of 452 elements I have, assigning them to the correct (1 of 9) variables.

1. The first for loop has 67 potential candidates
2. The second for loop has 112
3. 111
4. 147
5. 146
6. 145
7. 100
8. 444
9. 26

```
for(a = 0; a < 67; a++){
  var1 = arr[a]

  for(b = 0; b < 112; b++){
    var2 = arr[b]

    for(c = 0; c < 111; c++){
      var3 = arr[c]

      for(d = 0; d < 147; d++){
        var4 = arr[d]

        for(e = 0; e < 146; e++){
          var5 = arr[e];

          for(f = 0; f < 145; f++){
            var6 = arr[f];

            for(g = 0; g < 100; g++){
              var7 = arr[g];

              for(h = 0; h < 444; h++){
                var8 = arr[h];

                for(i = 0; i < 26; i++){
                  var9 = arr[i];
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So obviously this has way too many occurrences for my fingers, and my browsers to run. How does one go about better handling this? The amount of permutations/possible outcomes is obviously ridiculously high.

Edit: just did some mathematics with my fingers, and came up with a possible `2,992,335,707,297,664,000` outcomes. I suppose there's a chance this is wrong, which is just disappointing considering my fingers can no longer move...

Edit2: Added the loops and how it literally assigns the variables so many times you cry. Not sure why the code editor didn't like my code, so didn't format correctly. I don't like it either though.

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking and what the code might look like, but could you simplify your code and put it in your question so we can replicate the issue?

Comment: I can make the loops for you real quickly, gimme 1 second

Comment: There you go mate @KyleFalconer

Comment: Keep in mind that JavaScript is single threaded, so while your loops are executing, nothing else will be able to run. Depending on your environment, you might be able to use Web Workers to your advantage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Do you **really** need to go through all that data (like rendering something on an 2-exapixel device)? Seems like this is screaming to be refactored.

Comment: The domain space of your input is way too large -- that is in the order of 10^18 total iterations to go throughout it all, as you found out. JavaScript or not, the only relevant question imo, is : can you reduce this domain space for your underlying problem?

Comment: It's not really a freeze, it's just taking very very long. But what are you actually computing in the innermost loop body? Surely there's a much better algorithmic solution to your problem.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike That won't help in a case like this.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah I'm sure there's a better algorithm... I was just using one that was first to my head that covered all 100% possibilities. The inner calculates the most pts for the highest projection amongst the 9 variables.

Comment: One handles this by using a better algorithm. Or using async code to avoid freezing, but it will take insanely long so it won't be usable anyways.

Comment: @JohnBarr Show us that code and what "projection" you mean, otherwise we cannot help you.